# How can I adjust the legend when visualizing clusters in two dimensions?

Tags: python, clustering, pca, matplotlib

How can I change the legend as we can see now the legend has some cluster numbers missing. How can I adjust the legend so that it can show all the cluster numbers (such as Cluster 1, Cluster 2 etc, no it's only 0 3 6 9)? (codes I followed this link: [Perform k-means clustering over multiple columns](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48693/perform-k-means-clustering-over-multiple-columns))

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=10)
y2 = kmeans.fit_predict(scaled_data)

reduced_scaled_data = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(scaled_data)
results = pd.DataFrame(reduced_scaled_data,columns=['pca1','pca2'])
sns.scatterplot(x="pca1", y="pca2", hue=y2, data=results)
#y2 is my cluster number

plt.title('K-means Clustering with 2 dimensions')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Edit: the legend seem not the same, the cluster 0 should be the lightest color.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this is an annoying weirdness of seaborn. Just pass `legend='full'` as a parameter to `sns.scatterplot()`. So your code becomes:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=10)
y2 = kmeans.fit_predict(scaled_data)

reduced_scaled_data = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(scaled_data)
results = pd.DataFrame(reduced_scaled_data,columns=['pca1','pca2'])
sns.scatterplot(x="pca1", y="pca2", hue=y2, data=results, legend='full')
#y2 is my cluster number

plt.title('K-means Clustering with 2 dimensions')
plt.show()
```

I have no idea why you'd ever want half a legend! But the parameter defaults to 'brief'. Refer to the [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html):

> legend : “brief”, “full”, or False, optional
>
> How to draw the legend. If “brief”, numeric hue and size variables will be represented with a sample of evenly spaced values. If “full”, every group will get an entry in the legend. If False, no legend data is added and no legend is drawn.

**edit**: To have the clusters named in the format you're after, first create a list in the right format, and then call `plt.legend()` and pass that list as an argument to `legend()`:

```
legend = []
for i in np.unique(y2):
    legend.append('Cluster {0}'.format(i))

sns.scatterplot(x="pca1", y="pca2", hue=y2, data=results, legend='full')
#y2 is my cluster number

plt.title('K-means Clustering with 2 dimensions')
plt.legend(legend)
plt.show()
```

To change the location of the legend, use the `loc=` parameter in the `plt.legend()` call. For example `plt.legend(legend, loc='upper right')` or `plt.legend(legend, loc='upper left')`

Comment: Hi thanks now I get all the cluster number, but I want to custom them from '0,1,2,3...'to 'Cluster 0, Cluster 1...', and also the legend covers part of the plot, I might need to make the plot bigger, do you mind giving me some hints? Thanks again. Note that y2=[0,1,2,3...] @DanScally

Comment: @Cecilia that's reasonably easy too; see my edit.

Comment: Hi thank you soooo much! But now the legend is too large and cover my data points, I tried to change 'size_norm' but nothing happened, is there a way that I can make the legend smaller or make the whole plot larger?

Comment: @Cecilia you can use the loc parameter when calling plt.legend() to control where it goes. Passing `plt.legend(legend, loc='best')` will make it try to deconflict. Alternatively you can call `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(36,12))` **BEFORE** `sns.scatterplot()` to change the size of the whole plot. There might also be a way to control the size of the legend itself; try the plt.legend() documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I've solved it, but I compared the adjusted legend, the first cluster-Cluster 0 should be the one with the lightest colour, but it's the darkest one now, not sure why this happens, please see my edit. Thanks again.

Comment: @Cecilia oh yeah, that is weird. Not sure I'm afraid. I'll take a look at lunchtime

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan:)

Comment: Hey just wondering if you come up with any idea? I tried to solve it but still have no idea...