# Perform k-means clustering over multiple columns and get the cluster center values?

Tags: python, clustering, k-means

I read [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48693/perform-k-means-clustering-over-multiple-columns) how to show the number of clusters over $n$ columns.

I would like to know how to get in a table, the values of the clusters centers. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: The `KMeans` class stores the cluster centers in the `cluster_centers_` attribute, which returns an array of shape `(n_clusters, n_features)` (see also [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sklearn.clusters.KMeans` has an attribute `cluster_centers_`, which stores the array of cluster centers.

You can add them to the dataframe as new columns this way:

```
clusters = KMeans(n_clusters = n)
predict = clusters.fit_predict(data)
centers = pd.DataFrame(clusters.cluster_centers_[predict, :])
centers.index = data.index
data = pd.concat([data, centers], axis=1)
```